# Error 502 when new WP_Query is inside post loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to set up custom post feeds inside a custom post single template. Code works fine outside the single template or any other query (pages, posts). But when inside a loop. it gives error 502 "The page request was canceled because it took too long to complete". Error log is empty.

```
$args2 = array(
      'post_type'   => 'payout',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'tax_query'   => array(
       array(
           'taxonomy' => 'pay_connection',
           'field'    => 'slug',
           'terms'    => '30'
           )
      )
);
$newquery = new WP_Query( $args2 );
if ( have_posts() ) while ($newquery->have_posts()) : $newquery->the_post();
     $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
     echo $custom['pay_start'][0];
     echo $custom['pay_end'][0];
     echo '$'. $custom['net_pay'][0];
  endwhile; 
  wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: You're requesting too much data. The quickest approach is to give the server more execution time, and the better approach would be to structure your data in a way that you can access all of them using IDs in array keys or something similar.

Comment: " structure your data in a way that you can access all of them using IDs in array keys or something similar" Not really following here. This seems to be a pretty standard WP query

Comment: How much published "payout" posts do you have? Is this in a local/dev environment, or something online (test/UAT/prod)?

Comment: there is only 1 test post. It's in production environment.

Comment: Is there any other queries in that environment working correctly?

Comment: Yes. This query is working fine as long as it's outside any other loops.

Comment: Is that the whole code? Are you closing the `if ( have_posts() )` statement with a `endif` or something?

Comment: This is entire code. for some reason, when I close the if with endif, there is "unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF) " error. That's mostly the case with all wp post loops i had.